# Docker and anaconda and how to work with both

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, fenics

It looks like the [fenics library](https://fenicsproject.org/fenics-project-roadmap-2019/) can only be installed in Windows through Docker. I have never used Docker before, and I am really uncomfortable deviating from my usual habits using anaconda. In particular, I really like to be able to separate my work into project-specific environments where I install the necessary packages and dependencies and switch environments depending on the work that needs to be done.

I would also really like to use fenics as it appears to be an excellent platform to solve PDE's numerically, but I don't want Docker to take over my system. I would like to restrict fenics to one of my anaconda environments and mix it up with other python libraries (such as `pyvista`, `fipy` and `pygmsh` as needed.

Is there perhaps a compromise I can come to? Is it possible to install docker only for selected anaconda environments while keeping other environments the same?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [continuumio/anaconda](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda/)

```sh
docker run --rm -it continuumio/anaconda bash
```

note: it's somewhat complicated to access a docker-container from outside. I recommend using a jupyter notebook and to mount the notebooks as a volume. Also docker comes with lots of "interesting" quirks. I recommend to get familiar with it's basic concepts.